# npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12

Tags: node.js, npm, warnings

When I enter npm install -g mdb-cli, i get this warning:

```
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
```

I tried deleting and intalling core-js and also tried npm clean-install but I still get the same warning. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. `npm cache clean --force`
2. `npm i -D core-js@latest`